# Mule can't find xsd generated by Devkit

Tags: mule, devkit

I'm having issues the the xsd files that are generated with Devkit. Now the xsd file is generated fine but when trying to run the connector mule can't find the xsd.

I get errors of this sort:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 58; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/fooCloud/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mule-fooCloud.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

Now I have been having a deep look for the .xsd file and have found 4 references to it.

> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/fooCloud/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mule-fooCloud.xsd

But the actual xsd file only exists in the target/gernerated-sources folder. I have not seen it in the update-site.
zip

any ideas why mule keeps trying to reference the mule site for the xsd?

Comment: Within the update site there should be a jar file for the connector i.e mule-module-fooCloud-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. Within that jar the schema should be located in META-INF. Are you running this from a MuleStudio project, Maven or the connector project itself?

Comment: @RyanCarter thanks, there is a snapshot file in the target folder (not in the update-site) with the .xds file. Not sure how to proceed. I'm running in both a studio and connector project, both fail.

Comment: Try updating your connector project >  Right-click on the connector project in Mule Studio's package explorer and from the Maven submenu select Update Project. Or run mvn eclipse:eclipse from the command line. Also is your connector still version 1.0-SNAPSHOT? or have you changed the version in your POM?

Comment: @RyanCarter I've tried updating many times, also starting with clean poms for devkit, 3.3.0 3.3.2 3.4.0 3.5.0-andes + different studios/clean versions. its a bit of a black box to me I'm afraid when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the solution to this was to make sure all your .mflow files had the xsd path for your connector that matched the one in the spring schema in the update site. For some reason one of the xsd paths was pointing to the snapshot-1.0 where as this was supposed to point to something else.